# An iff proof concerning limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{a \to k_{0}} f(a) = b$ iff $\forall \{k_{n}\} \subseteq X$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} k_{n} \rightarrow k_{0} \Rightarrow \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}f(k_{n}) = b$.

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,p)$ be metric spaces.

If $k_{0} \in X$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{a \to k_{0}} f(a) = b \in Y$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall a \in X$, $d(a,k_{0}) < \delta \Rightarrow p(f(a), b) < \epsilon$.

I believe this is the right idea but I do not know how to conclude it. Also this is an iff statement so I need the other direction as well. The help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use the fact that for any sequence $k_n$, $d(k_0,k_n)$ can be made as small as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow):$ Suppose $\lim_{k_0} f(a)=b$, and let $\{k_n\}\subset X$ s.t $k_n\to k_0$, and let $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\eta>0$ s.t $d(a,k_0)<\eta\Rightarrow d(f(a),b)<\epsilon$, as $k_n\to k_0$ there exists $N\in \Bbb N$ s.t for all $n\geq N$ ; $d(k_n,k_0)<\eta$ hence for all $n\geq N$ , $d(f(a),b)<\epsilon$. This show that $f(k_n)\to b$.

$\Leftarrow):$ we suppose that $f(a)\not\to b$.
there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t for any $\eta$ there exists $a_{\eta}\in X$ s.t $d(a,k_0)<\eta$ but $d(f(a_{\eta}),b)\geq \epsilon$. for $\eta=\dfrac{1}{n}$, there exists $a_n\in X$ s.t $d(a_n,k_0)<\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $d(f(x_n),b)\geq \epsilon$.

But $a_n\to a$ and $f(a_n)\not\to b$.

Answer (score 0):

For one direction, consider the following:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. By the definition of $\lim_{a \rightarrow k_0} f(a) = b$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $$0 < |a - k_0| < \delta \implies |f(a) - b| < \epsilon.$$

Now, let $\{ k_n\} \subseteq X$ such that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} k_n = k_0.$$ Then there exists an $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|k_n - k_0| < \delta$. Using the definition of $\lim_{a \rightarrow k_0} f(a) = b$ above, this implies that $|f(k_n) - b| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Thus, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(k_n) = b$.

Hope this gives you a better idea on how to approach this problem. See if you can figure out the other direction. Please let me know if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0):

The other direction:

Suppose that $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to k_0}f(a)\neq b$.  Then there is some $\epsilon>0$, and a sequence of $a_n\to k_0$ such that $|f(a_n)-f(b)|>\epsilon$ for all $n$ (this is not completely trivial, but not hard to show).  Therefore the second statement cannot hold.